# PySpark How to parse and get field names from Dataframe schema's StructType Object

Tags: apache-spark, struct, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I have created Dataframe from Hive Table and want to retrieve the field/Column names.

```
>>>a=df.schema
>>>a
StructType(List(StructField(empid, IntegerType, true), StructField(empname,StringType, true)))
```

How can I retrieve Field names (empid, empname) from this object.

Answer (score 15):

Use [`pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fieldnames`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=fieldnames#pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fieldNames):

> `fieldNames()`
>
> Returns all field names in a list.
>
> ```
> >>> struct = StructType([StructField("f1", StringType(), True)])
> >>> struct.fieldNames()
> ['f1']
> ```

Comment: This is indeed hard to find, took me 2 hours so far, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use df.columns to get the column names as a list.

```
>>> spark.version
u'2.4.0.cloudera2'
>>>
>>> df=spark.sql("select 10 empid, 's' empname from range(1)")

>>> df.schema
StructType(List(StructField(empid,IntegerType,false),StructField(empname,StringType,false)))

>>> df.schema.fieldNames()
['empid', 'empname']

>>> df.columns
['empid', 'empname']
>>>
```

Comment: You answered to a different, more trivial question.